# vpn connection not open other ip

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vpn

in windows 2008 server i create a vpn server with custom configuration

and set ipv4 static address pool 192.168.200.1 to 192.168.200.30

then create a vpn connection in windows xp and connect to vpn server

connection successful connected but i can just open and brows server ip 's websites

and can not use for brows another website

what can i do?

excuse for bad english

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may need to enable IPv4 routing on your server in RRAS, and you should probably check your connection rules in NPAS to make sure the connection is allowed.